# How to get past error TF26038: System.Description was HTML, but now is PlainText

Tags: tfs, migrate

I am attempting to migrate, using the TFS Integration tool, an existing TFS 2010 project into to a new, empty TFS 2012 one and I get the TF26038 error.  Both projects were created using the Agile 5.0 process template.  It appears that this field is indeed a different type between 2010 and 2012, but I would assume the process template definition is all that would matter.  Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am migrating a project between TFS 2010 and TFS 11.  The problem is that the `System.Description` field changed types from plain text to HTML between those versions of TFS and can't be migrated.  To fix the issue, you simply have to exclude that field in your mappings:

```
               <MappedField LeftName="System.Description"
                            RightName="" MapFromSide="Left"
                            valueMap="" />
```

The field seemed to contain mostly redundant information anyway, so it wasn't a big loss.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj130558.aspx for more information.